# How to use sql unique index to restrict the number of `unfinalized` records

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have 3 entities in SQL: `User`, `Test` and `UserTestAttempt`.

```
class User {
  Long id;
}

class Test {
  Long id;
}

class UserTestAttempt {
  Long id;
  Long userId;
  Long testId;
  StatusEnum status; // REGISTERED, IN_PROGRESS, PASSED, FAILED
}
```

A `User` can make a `UserTestAttempt` to take a `Test`. However, when `status` is `REGISTERED` or `IN_PROGRESS`, no new `UserTestAttempt` can be created with identical `userId` and `testId`. After `status` turns into `PASSED` or `FAILED`, `User` can create new `UserTestAttempt` to retake `Test`.

Is there an easy way to achieve this through SQL unique index? Or I have to implement it in pure code?

Comment: you are stuck with code in this case.  if you split off the end_state (PASSED/FAILED) from the active state(REGISTERED/IN PROGRESS) then you can use a unique index on the active state along with user and test

Comment: @Randy with 2 columns, there will be null for active state, will unique index take effect in that case since we allow unlimited duplicate `PASSED` / `FAILED` attempts?

Comment: I believe it is a combination of CHECK and UNIQUE constraints. here is a reference for sql server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: It is not ture in mysql `A UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique Then how can I enforce the uniqueness over active state of `REGISTERED` or `IN_PROGRESS`